# Want to hyperlink to a controller method not a view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink

I want the Logout link to carry out a process located in `HomeController` and not to display a new `View`. How do I go about structuring this?

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult LogoutProcess()
    {
        previousLoggedIn = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
        WebSecurity.Logout();
        return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Home");
    }

    public ActionResult Logout(HomeModels.LogoutModel model)
    {
        model.PreviouslyLoggedInUsername = previousLoggedIn;
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
<a href = "@Url.Action("LogoutProcess", "Home")">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Have you thought about sending an AJAX request to the Home controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard link, targeting that action

```
@Url.Action("LogoutProcess", "Home")
```

The "trick" is in *Redirection* to some other View at the end of your `LogoutProcess()` action:

```
public ActionResult LogoutProcess()
{
    // TempData to transfer user name      
    TempData["previousLoggedIn"] = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
    WebSecurity.Logout();
    return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Home");
}

public ActionResult Logout(HomeModels.LogoutModel model)
{
    // fill model from TempData
    model.PreviouslyLoggedInUsername = TempData["previousLoggedIn"];
    return View(model);
}
```

The `CurrentUserName` is passed to other action via `TempData`

Comment: Will that then carry out the Index Controller?

Comment: The index is a name of action (as I was thinking about it) nested in HomeController. But it could be Account controller. Just adjust the Url.Action(actionName, controllerName) and Redirect from LogoutProcess to controller you want (Home, Account...) Make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Action, think I used the wrong word there. Thanks!

Comment: When I step through my code, it doesn't use the Logout action that I've defined in my controllers. I've updated my code above.

Comment: It's signing out correctly. Just the Goodbye <name> isn't showing up correctly.

Comment: I updated my answer. Put anyhting you want to pass to other action into `TempData` collection. It is designed exactly for these purposes...

Comment: Try to think about each request as a new instance of your Controller. No private fields will survive, while HomeController is recreated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult LogoutProcess()
{
    WebSecurity.Logout();
    //return null;
    Return RedirectToAction("Index");//or whatever page you want to display after logout.
}
```

Comment: When I step through my code, it doesn't use the Logout action that I've defined in my controllers. I've updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a no content http status code result?

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
```